# PHP takes a long time for uncached pages

Tags: php

On my server, PHP will take a long time to execute a script (say, 5 seconds) if it hasn't been cached by APC yet. After it is, it executes very fast.

I'd provide more information, but I wouldn't know where to begin. Can you guess and point me in the right direction? I'll edit this question once I have more info.

Comment: This questions is probably more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, this is most likely on the configuration side of things. If we can rule out config problems here, the author can make another post about code optimisation.

Comment: Bart, does your application use any remote php include()'s, or are all the included scripts local the server?

Comment: Everything is local. It's also bound to be something on the config side because 1. Some of the scripts are made by others (a MediaWiki, an SMF forum) 2. Some of the scripts have run on another server before, where they work fine.

Comment: Hmm, 5 seconds is still a long time for a php script to execute. What is the load like on that host ?

Comment: So go on and measure the time the script itself takes for execution. Put something lieke
echo "START " + microtime();
at the very start of the skript and a
echo "END " + microtime();
at the end. If the time is significantly lower than 1s you know there is a problem with the invocation of the script. If the execution time is nearly 5s it is the code which takes so long and you know this is not an administration problem.

Comment: It does take the script long to execute (as measured by SMF) but I'm convinced there's nothing wrong with the actual script. See my comment above this one and 3. The scripts work fast when they are cached by APC so it must be the including of the files that's taking a long time.

Comment: If the result is retrieved from the cache your script is not invoked at all. Don't guess the problem, look. You identified that your script takes long to execute. But which part of the script takes most of the time? Slice down your script into several "START, END" blocks (as described above). Look which block takes the longest time. Slice down this block. Repeat until you narrowed the problem down to a couple of lines. Then you'll know what's wrong.

Comment: APC does not cache the result, it caches the PHP bytecode. So yeah, it really is invoked, it's just not parsed again. I'm really certain it's not in the scripts themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why we have caches. ;)
Seriously: it seems that executing the script is the problem.
But is it:

- starting up the interpreter
- or: execution time of the script?

Is there a PHP module installed, or does the http server has to start a new process (php) for the script?

Are the disks busy?

What is the execution time of the script itself (easy to measure with two timestamps you print at the start and at the end of the script)?

Comment: I'm using Apache2's mod-php5. I wouldn't know about the disks. How can I find out? The server load is very low though, so it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) to profile your scripts. Then you'll know what takes so long.